# How to do async task without waiting for it to finish in python?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a program like this

```
task_2_running = False

async def task2():
    task_2_running = True
    await do_something()
    task_2_running = False

async def main():
    while True:
        x = await task1()
        do_something(x)
        if some_condition(x) and not task_2_running:
            #Do task2() but don't wait until it finished

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

How do I call `task2()` so the loop will continue without waiting for `task2()` to finish, and `task2()` will still finish sometime in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [asyncio.create_task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task), a sample as next:

**test.py:**

```
import time

task_2_running = False

async def task1():
    time.sleep(3)

async def task2():
    print("task2 run")
    task_2_running = True
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    task_2_running = False
    print("task2 finish")

async def main():
    while True:
        print("main run")
        x = await task1()
        if not task_2_running:
            print("create task2")
            #Do task2() but don't wait until it finished
            asyncio.create_task(task2())
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

**Execution:**

```
$ python3 test.py
main run
create task2
task2 run
main run
create task2
task2 run
task2 finish
main run
create task2
task2 run
^C
```

From the execution, you could see after `task2 run`, the `main run` did not wait for `task2 finish`, just continue to run next loop to print another `main run`.

BTW, `asyncio.create_task` just for python3.7 and higher, for `< python3.7`, you may need to use `asyncio.ensure_future()`, see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future):

```
async def coro():
    ...

# In Python 3.7+
task = asyncio.create_task(coro())
...

# This works in all Python versions but is less readable
task = asyncio.ensure_future(coro())
...
```

Comment: How does `loop.run_until_complete` answer "[run] task without waiting for it to complete"?

Comment: For a asyncio program, there is always a `io-loop` there, here is `loop.run_until_complete`. When we say `run task without waiting`, it means `there is some logic still need be run in current coroutine, we shouldn't use await, otherwise the CPU time yield to other task in in other coroutine, current coroutine won't have chance to run`, this is the value of `create task`, this is not related to the main io loop.

Comment: I am looking how to run an `asyncio` coroutine or task from synchronous code without waiting for completion. It seems this is impossible, and that the only way to do it is to start an event loop in its own, non-main thread, create the tasks there, and then run them until complete in that thread. Is that true?

Comment: Looks like this, the main event loop will always there to block you run following code... Unless like what you said, use a thread, looks ugly but I don't know other solution...